# Errors were encountered while processing: install-info

Tags: command-line, syntax

```
$ sudo apt-get install wondershaper python-qt4 arp-scan dsniff arptables

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-qt4 is already the newest version (4.11.4+dfsg-1build4).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnet1 libnids1.21
The following NEW packages will be installed
  arp-scan arptables dsniff libnet1 libnids1.21 wondershaper
0 to upgrade, 6 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/419 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,468 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 5: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following in a file and save it in your Desktop as `askubuntu`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# update-info-dir
# create a dir file from all installed info files
# Copyright 2009, 2014 Norbert Preining
# GPLv2

INFODIR=/usr/share/info

set -e

#
# since user's environment is taken over into root account when sudo-ing
# we don't want that one's user LANGUAGE setting changes the messages in
# the dir file. Unset LANGUAGE and reload /etc/environment to get
# the system wide settings. See bug #536476
unset LANGUAGE
unset LANG
if [ -r /etc/environment ] ; then
  . /etc/environment
fi
if [ -r /etc/default/locale ] ; then
  . /etc/default/locale
fi

Help ()
{
    echo "\
SYNOPSIS: update-info-dir [-h,--help] [info-directory]

(re-)creates the index of available documentation in info format
(the file /usr/share/info/dir) which is usually presented by info browsers
on startup."

    exit 0
}


if [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    Help
fi

if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
  INFODIR="$1"
fi

if [ ! -d "$INFODIR" ] ; then
  echo "Not a directory: $INFODIR." >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ -r "$INFODIR/dir" ] ; then
  rm -f "$INFODIR/dir.old"
  cp $INFODIR/dir $INFODIR/dir.old
fi

# we have to remove the dir file not make install-info being surprised
rm -f "$INFODIR/dir"

errors=0
find "$INFODIR" -type f | while read file ; do
  case $file in
    */dir|*/dir.gz|*/dir.old|*/dir.old.gz|*-[0-9]|*-[0-9].gz|*-[1-9][0-9]|*-[1-9][0-9].gz|*.png|*.jpg)
      # these files are ignored
      continue
      ;;
    *)
      install-info "$file" "$INFODIR/dir" || {
        errors=$((errors+1))
      }
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ $errors -gt 0 ] ; then
  exec >&2
  echo
  echo "Updating the index of info documentation produced $errors errors."
fi

exit 0

# vim:set expandtab tabstop=2: #
```

- Open a terminal and run:

  - `sudo cp /usr/sbin/update-info-dir /usr/sbin/update-info-dir-backup`
  - `sudo rm /usr/sbin/update-info-dir`
  - `sudo cat ~/Desktop/askubuntu | sudo tee /usr/sbin/update-info-dir`
  - `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/update-info-dir`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you said but upon running the first terminal command you listed I got this error:                                                          cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/sbin/update-info-dir-backup': Permission denied

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `sudo`. Edited it now, you can try again.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The first two or so commands worked but now I have this:                                                                                               grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ sudo cp /usr/sbin/update-info-dir /usr/sbin/update-info-dir-backup
[sudo] password for grimy1928: 
grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ sudo rm /usr/sbin/update-info-dir
grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $ sudo cat ~/Desktop/askubuntu >> /usr/sbin/update-info-dir
bash: /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: Permission denied
grimy1928@Adam-SATELLITE-C50D-A-12V ~ $

Comment: Now run this `cat ~/Desktop/askubuntu | sudo tee /usr/sbin/update-info-dir`

Comment: Okay thanks, I've done this now                                                                           "sudo cp /usr/sbin/update-info-dir /usr/sbin/update-info-dir-backup"
"sudo rm /usr/sbin/update-info-dir"                                                                          "cat ~/Desktop/askubuntu | sudo tee /usr/sbin/update-info-dir"            "sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/update-info-dir"

Comment: Now try to install the programs you wanted in the first place

Comment: @AdamJones did it work?

Comment: No, it didn't work unfortunately but I found out that there was a missing speech mark for the file at /etc/environment and that sorted it. I really appreciate the help though as what you said to do has likely helped me to stop getting other potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to delete a quote-sign in `/etc/default/locale` from this:

```
LC_TIME=""en_US.UTF-8"
```

to this

```
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```